# Serilog how read from azure appservice's configuration the ApplicationInsights connectionstring

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-application-insights, serilog

I'm using Serilog and ApplicationInsight with few effort putting this in program.cs

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));
```

and this in appsettings.json

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=a1b28ea5...;IngestionEndpoint=....",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
  }
```

and it works!

BUT...I would like to have the connectionstring in the configuration of the appservice, because I deploy via azure pipeline the app in 2 different appservices -staging and production- (that have 2 different applicationinsights connstring).

Is it possible? Maybe with a Pipeline variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to have the connectionstring in the configuration of the appservice,

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sdk-connection-string?tabs=net#environment-variable) add new Application setting in `Azure App Service` configuration section.

Navigate to the `Azure Portal` => Your `App Service` => `Configuration` => `Application settings`.

[image]

- Add new key-value with `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING`
  and values as Connection String from `ApplicationInsights`.

[image]

Instead of setting the `connectionString` in `appsettings.json` you can set the Environment variable `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` to work locally.

- Right click on the project root folder => `Properties` =>select `General` under  `Debug` => click on `Open debug launchprofiles UI` .

[image]
Now modify the code in `Program.cs` file as below.

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration=new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"), new TraceTelemetryConverter());
Log.Logger = log.CreateLogger();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));
var app = builder.Build();
```

- Set the `APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` for each environment in Azure Pipeline variables.
- Open your `pipeline` => click on `edit` => `Variables`.
- Add new Variables for `APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` and provide the `connectionstring`.

[image]

- As you need for both staging and production, create 2 variables for each slot.
- In the Azure App Service deploy task, add the `App settings` Environment Variables as shown below.

```cs
    AppSettings:  'APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=$(YourVariableName)'
```

[image]

- Select `Deploy to Slot or App Service Environment` option.

[image]

- Select the required slot and the specific variable for the slot.
- Under `Application and Configuration` settings provide the value.
  [image]
- After successful deployment you can see the App Setting in `Configuration` section available as mentioned in the initial steps of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for my very late response (I was 3 weeks out due covid+flu!). Thanks a lot for your articulate answer and the time you took to create all the screenshots. I tried the first steps and they work flawless; I have only a doubt when you say "As you need for both staging and production, create 2 variables for each slot."
I have only a pipeline with two stages that create 2 releases in different app-services; how I bind the stage with the right variable? Anyway, again, thanks a lot!